# how to map multiple listeners on a network load balancer to a single target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have created a network balancer in AWS that has multiple listeners listening on various different ports. But they all need to forward to one EC2 instance. Is there a way to do this without creating multiple target groups? The problem I am finding is with the port mapping. There doesn't seem to be an option to map to a port range, so unfortunately as it currently stands they all map to port 8383, which isn't going to work. The idea of creating multiple target groups to map all the listeners even though the target instance is the same seems odd. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you will need to create individual target groups and add the server there.

As you rightly pointed out, target groups are single port entities.